# Oracle - multiple entries within a range question

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle 12.2, I have a table which lists events...approx 1.3 M events...

```
  Event_Date  DATE,
  Person_ID Number,
  Person_Name VARCHAR2(100), 
  Event_Name_Tier1  VARCHAR2(100),
  ...
```

I need a query which says...

Show me all occurrences where a PERSON has a row for Event_Name_Tier1 = 'ABC' **and** that same person has another row (in same table) where Event_Name_Tier1 = (One of about 15 values, for example 'S2', 'T4', 'G7', 'Y9')) provided both records were within 90 days of each other.

How do I go about writing this?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I am at a loss what to attempt.  This appears to be some type of a self-join, but beyond that...

Comment: Which part presents a problem for you?

Comment: You can use `WHERE EXISTS` with your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nature of your question, I'm thinking something like:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.Event_Name_Tier1 = 'ABC' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.person_id = t.person_id and
                    t2.Event_Name_Tier1 in ('S2', 'T4', 'G7', 'Y9', . . . ) and 
                    t2.event_date > t.event_date and
                    t2.event_date < t.event_date + interval '90' day
             );
```